# Embed linkedin post - Refused to frame and DOMException

Tags: iframe, linkedin-api, content-security-policy

I am trying to embed a linkedin post, just click on embed option they provide and copy the html.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4ocnxepb/

This works fine apparently, but the console has a lot of errors:

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://www.linkedin.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

urn:li:share:6788184218288590848:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: getInstalledRelatedApps() is only supported in top-level browsing contexts.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The response to https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6788184218288590848  sets Content-Security-Policy without frame-ancestors and Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only with frame-ancestors 'none' in the response headers. Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only violations show up as error in the console and a report is sent if report-uri or report-to is specified, but it is blocked in the browser.

You can't really fix this unless you proxy the requests to remove the header. LinkedIn may do this to gather statistics on how much posts are embedded. It may also be that they are testing out a stricter CSP that may be enforced at some point in the future preventing embedding in this way.